# strtolower warning when sent array to a function php

Tags: php

I have this function to check if the url is an image:

```
function isImage($url){
$url_headers=get_headers($url, 1);
    if(isset($url_headers['Content-Type'])){
        $type=strtolower($url_headers['Content-Type']); // strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

        $valid_image_type=array();
        $valid_image_type['image/png']='';
        $valid_image_type['image/jpg']='';

        if(isset($valid_image_type[$type])){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and this:

```
if(isImage($matches[0])){ //do something }
```

it was a array, but I get the value in position 0 and send it to a function. what is the problem here? I want only position 0. Any ideas how to solve the warning?

Comment: Have you tried using `print_r($url_headers['Content-Type']);` to check what the value is?

Comment: I guess it's something like in [this example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#100113). The warning is quite clear...

Comment: oh, when it is an image, it gives me: `image/jpeg` and when it is not: `Array ( [0] => text/html; charset=utf-8 [1] => text/html; charset=utf-8 )` @NigelRen

Comment: So you should check it with is_array!

Comment: `if(!is_array($url_headers['Content-Type'])){
   $type=strtolower($url_headers['Content-Type']);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

it cant be 100% sure that it will always comeback with true but anyway like "Shujaat" suggest first you should check for :

1- Headers Content instead of only extension (works even if the image is being served dynamically with the extension of ".php" or anything else)

2- verify the header content length to make sure it's bigger than 0 and the server is not sending a `HTTP/1.1 404`

3 - verify if the image is a redirect. (in case of 404 page or a default image file)

**basic example :**

```
// URL
 $url = "https://packagecontrol.io/img/book5.png";

// verify the URL is exists or not
$get_headers = @get_headers($url);

if($get_headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
   $url_exists = false;
} else {
$url_exists = true;
}

// verify if the URL is image
if($url_exists){
 if(isset($get_headers['Content-Type'])){

    $type = strtolower($get_headers['Content-Type']);

    $valid_image_type = array();
    $valid_image_type['image/png']      = '';
    $valid_image_type['image/jpg']      = '';
    $valid_image_type['image/jpeg']     = '';

    if(isset($valid_image_type[$type])){
        // success
    } else {
        // fail.
    }
  }
} else {
// throw "URL does not Exist"
}
```

**- other ways** :
in my opinion the faster way to do it is with this project which is running on JavaScript
and its really good :[Here](https://gist.github.com/bgrins/6194623)

> live demo : [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/aZWTB/)